# Why this function are in infinite loop?

Tags: c, gcc, scanf, infinite-loop

This function just stay in a loop while my user dont type the right input(in this case an integer). The infinite loop happens when the user type the wrong value(like a string). But why this happen? And how to fix that?

```
int main(void) {
  int colQty;
  int result = 0;
  while (result != 1) {
    printf("Informe a quantidade de colunas: ");
    result = scanf("%d", &colQty);
    if (result != 1) {
      printf("Erro! Verifique se os valores de entrada estão certos.");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf does not skip input. It just stops when the format doesn't match

Comment: @stark can you explain more about this? Please! I cant understand.

Comment: Whatever the user typed is still waiting to be read. When you get 0 from sscanf, you could read and ignore the rest of the line with fgets.

Answer (score 4):

`scanf` stops on the wrong input and does not skip it. Your code is keep scanning the same input all over again. Usually, it is better to read the line and `sscanf` the string.

```
char line[100];
printf("\nInforme a quantidade de colunas: ");
if(!fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {/* handle error */}
result = sscanf(line, "%d", &colQty);
```

Comment: It works. but the code does not enter the if, what is the reason? I put a print inside the if, but it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by *@gulpr*, `scanf()` leaves the offending input in the input stream, so the next iteration keeps failing to no avail.  The same problem would occur at the end of file, for example if the input stream is redirected from an empty file.

It is recommended to read input one line at a time and use `sscanf` to parse the user input from the line.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int colQty;

    for (;;) {
        char input[100];
        printf("Informe a quantidade de colunas: ");
        if (!fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
            printf("Error: no input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (sscanf(input, "%d", &colQty) == 1) {
            // conversion succeeded, proceed
            break;
        }
        printf("Error: input is not a number: %s", input);
    }
    printf("colQty: %d\n", colQty);
    return 0;
}
```